# Server-Side State Management in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am in the process of migrating an ASP.NET web forms application to ASP.NET MVC 3. In my web forms project, we use the Application object to store some temporary information that we want to pass around on the server. We do not want to pass this information back to the client.

My question is, is there an equivalent to the Application object in ASP.NET MVC 3 to handle server-side state management?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the "object" is the same and can be accessed in a similar manner. `MVC` is built "on top of" `ASP.Net` so you can expect to have access to most of the same `data structures` like `HttpContext.Session` and `HttpContext.Application`.

Comment: same linraries available as stated- obviously with the session recycling every 20 minutes does not sound like a good plan anyway :-)